# RS232 to TTL Converter Voltages

Tags: serial-port, esp32

I am using an RS232 to TTL converter such as this one

[RS232 to TTL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08FHZT4DM)

It is coming from a 232 line and is transmitting serial to my ESP32 (logic level 3.3). Is there anything I need to do to ensure that the logic levels are at the same level ? I was kind of assuming that it could convert between 5 and 3.3 logic levels. And, I could just use the Tx and GND from the board to my ESP32. However, maybe I need to use the Vcc pin on the board so that it converts from 5V to 3.3V. Because otherwise I will be frying my receive pin on my ESP32.

I am new to this, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I read more about the MAX232 IC and I am realizing that I definitely need to power it with 3.3 because I believe that is how the logic level transitions are done on the board.

Comment: A cheapo but working solution is to just put a voltage divider on the RX pin of the ESP32 to bring down the voltage from 5V to 3.3V. In the other direction in most cases the 3.3V signal from the ESP32 is enough for the TTL side to receive properly.  
This is just a quick and dirty way to do it that usually works but not always, so whether to use it or not depends on how important it is for you that it works reliably.
The correct way is of course to use a MAX232 or something like that but I found in most cases I can get away with the voltage divider arrangement.